# Retain Current AppSettings for Production Azure Function Slot in ARM

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I'm looking to implement a staging slot for an Azure function. The approach I'm attempting to take is to define the slot in the ARM template along with the rest of the infrastructure and the app settings. I'll then deploy the app to the staging slot and perform a slot swap using `az`.

The problem I have is that the app settings sometimes contains settings specific to the version of the app running. Within the ARM template, I want to apply new application setting to the staging slot whilst retaining the currently set value for some of the settings on the production slot. These production slot settings should then only be updated when the swap occurs in the next couple of steps.

I've not been able to find a way to express this within ARM. I've attempted to use reference to set the appsetting property to be its current value. I'm not sure if this is possible but I get a generic validation error with no detail on why it's failed.

Is there a way to leave some appsettings unchanged in ARM?

UPDATE

Here is a snippet of my attempt to retain the existing value of the config.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
    "name": "MyApp/appsettings",
    "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
    "properties": {
        "MY_APP_CONFIG1": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', 'MyApp', 'appsettings'), '2019-08-01', 'Full').properties.MY_APP_CONFIG1]"
    }
}
```

The reference function introduced here fails the template validation. Only information it gives me is `The deployment validation failed`.

Answer (score 0):

no, you have to set all of them in the template. to pass different values to the template you are using to deploy to different environments (slots) you can use parameters (or parameter files). you can probably get a reference of the current value with the `reference(xxx, xxx, 'Full')`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#reference

Comment: Yea, I've tried using reference but I haven't been able to get it to work. I'll try and persist with it. Error wasn't descriptive at all.

Comment: if you can add you arm template I can look at it

Comment: Update the question to include a snippet of the template.

Comment: try `.properties.siteconfig.appSettings.MY_APP_CONFIG1` but looking at the api, i think its an array, lookups are not supported for arrays

Answer (score 0):

I've found following call:

```
"value": "[list(format('{0}/config/appsettings', variables('funID')), '2020-06-01').properties.MY_APP_CONFIG1]"
```

Hope it will be usefull.